# Control Design: Continuous State Space vs. Digital State Space --> Feedforward Path

Tags: control

I have a question regarding the state space representation of a model.

I created a continuous model of my plant in Simulink, which does not contain a direct path from input to output, i.e. the D Matrix is zero. The model contains 3 zeros and 5 poles.

For further computations I have to convert this continuous model into a digital model. I use the bilinear transformation to do so.

The digital transfer function in the z domain contains now 5 zeros and 5 poles, which leads to a nonzero feedforward coefficient D in the state space representation.

I am not surprised that the digital model has more zeros than the continuous model, however, I can't see the connection between my digital model and the 'physical' model in Simulink. 
What I want to say is that the real machine does not contain a direct path while the digital representation does. How can I create a understandable linkage between those two representations?

Unfortunately I could not find books/papers about this topic, maybe you can give me a hint?

Thanks in advance for your help!

hypn0

Answer (score 1):

The bilinear transform will always provide equal orders of numerator and denominator polynomials in the ZTF. A good alternative is to use pole and zero mapping, via z -> exp(sT), with appropriate adjustment of DC gain